# create-react-app material-ui build

Tags: material-ui, create-react-app

I'm use create-react-app and material-ui@next

After I run yarn build I got error

```
Failed to minify the code from this file:
./node_modules/material-ui/es/Typography/Typography.js
Read more here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-build-fails-to-minify
```

How I can fix this error

Comment: which version was installed with ```yarn add material-ui@next```?? i'm using the same and i have no problems creating builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run

```
npx babel node_modules\material-ui --out-dir node_modules\material-ui --presets=env,react
```

before

```
yarn build
```